# Cannot access statistics - WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 BAM

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-bam

I have installed this man times now only to get the same issues. Upon clicking stats in the publisher / store i get referred to the wiki and in the carbon i get the errors below -

> TID[-1234] [AM] [2014-07-01 15:42:26,892] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} - Error
>   while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:115)
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getFirstAccessTime(APIProviderHostObject.java:3937)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1._c_getFirstAccessTime_14(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag:382)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0._c_anonymous_14(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag:31)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag:47)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag:4)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag)
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.jag)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

FOLLOWED BY

> TID[-1234] [AM] [2014-07-01 15:42:26,985] ERROR
>   {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Can any one help please?

Thanks,

Ash.

UPDATE -

After working out it is an issue with API-M reading the RDBMS (Thanks to Nadeesha), I have got this log from the API-M console after attempting to access the publisher stats

> [2014-07-02 10:26:03,279] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error while
>   invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException:
>   Exception while instantiating API manager core objects
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:115)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getFirstAccessTime(APIProviderHostObject.java:3937)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1._c_getFirstAccessTime_14(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag:382)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0._c_anonymous_14(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag:31)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/aja
>   x/stats.jag:47)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.ja
>   g)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/s
>   tats.jag:4)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.ja
>   g)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.ja
>   g)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.api_subscriptions.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/api-subscriptions/ajax/stats.ja
>   g)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\WSO2AM~1.0\bin..\repository\conf\billing-conf.xml (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:106)
>           ... 62 more [2014-07-02 10:26:03,404] ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to debug whats going wrong. How API-M and BAM integration works is that

1. API -> publish stats to BAM
2. BAM stores the stats in Cassandra
3. BAM uses Hive scripts to analyse the data and write the results to a RDBMS mentioned in master-datasources.xml

I would recommend you to check the number 2. by checking if stats are published to BAM. You can do this by login into the management console of BAM and going to the Analytic section and adding the following script

```
select * from  APIRequestData;
```

Execute this script and see if any data is returned. If no data is returned then data is not correctly published from API-M to BAM. If data is available here then there is an issue in reading the data from RDBMS to API-M.

Comment: Hi @Nadeesha, thank you so much for this, i Have established that there is data returned from that query in BAM. Does this mean i need to re configure something in the API-M? If so, which scripts should I revise? Thank you again, Ash.

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo i fixed the problem! Thanks to Nadeesha for pointing out that API-M wasnt reading the RDBMS data properly (See here to check that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24523906/84546)

I then found a mysterious billing-conf.xml not found message in the WSO2 console log, after a little research change the  tag inside repository/conf/api-manager.xml from true to false

```
<!--
        Enable/Disable Usage metering and billing for api usage
     -->
     <EnableBillingAndUsage>**false**</EnableBillingAndUsage>
```

Voila! It started to work!

Thanks,

Ash.